# Exclude lines that have less than 23 columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like delete (exclude from output) some lines that have less than 23 columns in a file. For example:

```
BR1009298 338 1685 5839 1986 21111995 1 1 1 0 20032001 954 31266 1 1 4 5 205 95 27 3 2 BR1009298
BR1009304 339 5835 5797 1986 23011996 0 1 1 0 5081997 961 11189 3 1 3 4 1007 96 28 3 3 BR1009304
BR1009306 340 1578 0 1986 4041997 0 1 1 0 15081997 972 11189 9 1 9 9 501 97 42 3 0 
BR1009309 112180 5910 5791 1986 9011996 1 1 1 0 22111999 961 5445 5 1 1 1 1007 96 28 3 4 BR1009309
```

I would like delete the 3rd line, because it only has 22 columns. It is a big file and all lines that don't have 23 columns need be removed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk 'NF >= 23' file
```

Comment: The right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

`perl -ane 'if ($#F >= 22) { print }' < t` where `t` contains your input data.

Note it's 22 because array's index start at 0 in perl.

Answer (score 0):

And with good 'ol `grep`:

```
grep -E '(\s+\S+){22}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly know as Perl6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put if .words >= 23;'  file > tmp
```

Raku's `words` routine splits on whitespace, giving you the desired column count. If the column count is greater-than-or-equal-to 23, then `$_.put` output the line.

FYI, `.put` is short for `$_.put`, where `$_` is Raku/Perl's "topic variable", in this case--successive input lines.

Note:  re-direct the output to a new file, e.g. `tmp`. Raku doesn't have a `-i` flag for "in-place" editing of files (and indeed, may never have it).

https://raku.org